# Efficient SQL that select a column with a keyword but exclude another word at the same time

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, search

I want to search from a table that includes certain keyword but at the same time the resulting records should not contain another word.

Example:

```
row 1: "resf xxx yyy zzz sdf"
row 2: "as yyy bbb aaa efw"
row 3: "dfs zzz hhh kkk asdf"
row 4: "fds uuu rrr yyy saf"
```

I want to find all rows that contains 'yyy' but exclude 'zzz', so the result should be row 2 and row 4.

What's the most efficient SQL to achieve this? I used the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [col name] LIKE '%yyy%' and [col name] NOT LIKE '%zzz%'
```

You can use any database engine. Any suggestion on the database design such as table structure or use of index is also appreciated.

Comment: Which database engine you are using

Comment: Your query is as efficient as you are going to get.  You need to fix the data structure to store each keyword in a separate row rather than in a space delimited character column.  Or, use a full-text index.

Comment: @VR46 you can use any database engine.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient SQL"? Using as less resources as possible? Being faster? ... Every query compiler will use different techniques to optimise  SQL execution.

Comment: @mauro by 'efficient' I mean fast. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Generally speaking you will have to _prepare_ data in the "right way" in advance in order to get faster queries afterwords. The "right way" differs from one database to another. Last thing: be aware... most DB compiler are "cost based". Their scope is to reduce Query cost in terms of network/disk IO ( memory and CPU usage/... more than run the Query "faster".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `FULL TEXT INDEX` to do this. Create a `FULL TEXT INDEX` on `[col name]` column.

Query will be something like

```
SELECT * FROM [table] 
WHERE Contains([col name],'yyy')
  AND  NOT Contains([col name],'zzz')
```

`Full Text Search` (`CONTAINS`) will be **faster/efficient** than using `LIKE` with wildcard's.

**Note:** This is applicable to `Sql Server`

Also if `"resf xxx yyy zzz sdf"` has more than one *property/data* inside it, then store each property in different column. Which can make your life easier when you want to query the data

Here are few links to create `FULL TEXT SEARCH`

- [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)
- [**Simple Talk**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/)
- [**Sql Authority(Pinal Dave)**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/)
- [**Sqlmag**](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/sample-full-text-search-engine)